# Separating scaling, rotation and sheer coefficients correctly in this case

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

This question follows-on from [Correct the Fourier transform of a shear-distorted image? ($x_{new} = x + \alpha y$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044248/284619). I have a group of distorted $x, y$ points and have found a matrix $A$ that corrects their positions:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x' \\
    y' \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{xx} & a_{xy}  \\
    a_{yx} & a_{yy} \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I now want to break this up into three separate terms, one for pure scaling or magnification $M$, one for pure rotation $R$, and one for shear $S$. I think they will look like this:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
    m_x & 0\\
    0 & m_y \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$R = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
    \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$S = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & s_{xy}  \\
    s_{yx} & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$

I see there are answers to

- [Separating Out Parts of a Matrix (Translation, Rotation, Scaling)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94787/284619)
- [Is it true that any matrix can be decomposed into product of rotation,reflection,shear,scaling and projection matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109108/284619)

and I recognize that those answers may apply to my problem, but they are beyond me; I need a simpler, more applied answer, or at least assistance getting there.

**Q1:** I can imagine setting $A$ equal to the product, but I'm worried if the order matters. Will this order work? Would any order work equally as well?

$$A = R \ S \ M $$

**Q2:** I now have five parameters instead of four. Since I've separated out rotation, should I now use only one shear, i.e. I have to choose only one of $s_xy$ or $s_yx$ and set the other to zero? Or just use $s_{xy} = s_{yx} = s$?

$$S = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & s  \\
    s & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Comment: In 2d, shearing both in x and in y, with "anti symmetric" off diagonal terms is a rotation and an isotropic scaling, so actually, shearing subsums rotation, unless you define shearing to only be in the x (y) direction. Order indeed matters, so set a convention and stick with it.

Comment: @user619894 yes I see, I didn't want that minus sign (have updated) *thanks!* https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN22h.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already observed the bad effect if you use $-s$ and $s$ in the off-diagonal terms of your "shear" matrix (making an antisymmetric matrix) -- the matrix doesn't just **look** like a rotation matrix, it actually **is** a combined rotation and scaling.

Changing the form of the matrix to a symmetric matrix **does not help**, because
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & s  \\ s & 1 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\left(-\frac\pi4\right) & -\sin\left(-\frac\pi4\right)  \\
            \sin\left(-\frac\pi4\right) & \cos\left(-\frac\pi4\right) \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 - s & 0  \\ 0 & 1 + s \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\left(\frac\pi4\right) & -\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)  \\
             \sin\left(\frac\pi4\right) & \cos\left(\frac\pi4\right) \end{bmatrix}.
$$
That is, the effect of the symmetric matrix is what we get by rotating $\frac\pi4$ radians counterclockwise, dilating by a factor $1-s$ in the direction of the $x$ axis and $1+s$ in the direction of the $y$ axis, and rotating back by $\frac\pi4$ radians clockwise.
Equivalently, it is a dilation by $1-s$ in the direction of the vector
$[1,-1]^T$ and a dilation by $1+s$ in the direction of the vector $[1,1]^T.$

As a more concrete way of looking at it, just observe what the transformation does to the unit square: it distorts it into a rhombus for any value of $s.$ This is just stretching, compressing, or even reflecting it along its two diagonals; there is no shear at all.

On the other hand, if you look at the effect on the unit square of a transformation by the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s  \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, $$
it is clearly a shear transformation: the vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are unaffected, while the vertices $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are both moved $s$ units to the right.

---

Now let's see how we can decompose an arbitrary $2\times2$ matrix into matrices for rotation, scaling, and shear. We start with
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}. $$
(Since there are only four entries, I find it simple enough to keep track of them by name rather than by subscripts, and the formulas will be less "busy" this way.)
Note what happens if we apply a rotation of $\theta$ radians to this matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta & b \cos\theta - d \sin\theta \\
c \cos\theta + a \sin\theta & d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Let $\theta = -\operatorname{atan2}(c, a)$ where $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the two-parameter arc tangent function
(see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3080759/139123) for a definition).
Then $\sin\theta = -\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}$ and
$\cos\theta = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}$,
so $c \cos\theta + a \sin\theta = 0.$
Define a rotation matrix $Q$ (not $R$; let's reserve the name $R$ for later) by
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
Q A = 
\begin{bmatrix} a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta & b \cos\theta - d \sin\theta \\
            0 & d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Suppose $a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta \neq 0$
and $d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \neq 0.$
(The alternative is that the matrix $QA$ is a projection and therefore so is the original matrix $A$.)
Define a scaling matrix $N$ (saving the name $M$ for later) by
$$
N = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta} & 0 \\
                    0 & \frac{1}{d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
NQA =
 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{b\cos\theta - d\sin\theta}{a\cos\theta - c\sin\theta}\\
                 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is a shear. So let $NQA = S$ and multiply both sides of the equation by
$Q^{-1}N^{-1}$; then
$$
A = Q^{-1} N^{-1} S = RMS
$$
where
\begin{align}
R &= Q^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} & \frac{-c}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} \\
   \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} & \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} \end{bmatrix}, \\
M &= N^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta & 0 \\
                    0 & d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{a^2 + c^2} & 0 \\
                    0 & \frac{ad-bc}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} \end{bmatrix}, \\
S &=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 &
        \frac{b\cos\theta - d\sin\theta}{a\cos\theta - c\sin\theta}\\
                 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{ab + cd}{a^2 + c^2} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

This is good for every matrix $A$ except the case where $a = c = 0,$
which is a projection and therefore presumably not what you would use to "correct" the positions of points.
For completeness, however, if $a = c = 0$ and $b^2 + d^2 \neq 0$ we can write
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{d}{\sqrt{b^2 + d^2}} & \frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2 + d^2}} \\
   \frac{-b}{\sqrt{b^2 + d^2}} & \frac{d}{\sqrt{b^2 + d^2}} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{b^2 + d^2} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & s  \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $s$ is whatever you like, that is, $A=RMS$ where $R$ is a rotation, $M$ is a scaling matrix (where $m_x = 0$) and $S$ is a shear.

And in the final case, $a = b = c = d,$ obviously you can just set $M$ to the zero matrix (that is, $m_x = m_y = 0$) and use any shear and rotation you like.

So it is indeed always possible to decompose $A$ into a product of the form $RMS,$
even in the cases you probably don't care about.

---

This suggests that it is possible to use another sequence such as $RSM,$
and indeed that particular sequence is possible.
In the $RMS$ derivation, the next step after zeroing out the lower left corner (via rotation) was to scale so that the diagonals are $1$
(which immediately gives you a shear matrix);
for $RSM,$ let's use a shear to produce a diagonal matrix.
That is, constructing $Q$ as before we have
$$
Q A =
\begin{bmatrix} a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta & b \cos\theta - d \sin\theta \\
            0 & d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}.
$$
A shear parallel to the $x$ axis will have no affect on the first column of this matrix, but the effect on the second column can be seen in
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & t  \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} b \cos\theta - d \sin\theta \\
                d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} t(d\cos\theta + b\sin\theta) + b\cos\theta - d\sin\theta \\
                d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}.
$$
We need
$t(d\cos\theta + b\sin\theta) + b\cos\theta - d\sin\theta = 0,$
which we get by setting
$t = \frac{d\sin\theta - b\cos\theta}{d\cos\theta + b\sin\theta}.$

but the derivation might be a little more difficult to find (I have not tried)
and we should expect the resulting formulas to be quite different.
Then
$$
TQA =
\begin{bmatrix} a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta & 0 \\
            0 & d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $T$ is the shear matrix
$$
T =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 &
        \frac{d\sin\theta - b\cos\theta}{d\cos\theta + b\sin\theta}\\
          0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\frac{ab + cd}{ad - bc} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
We see that $M = TQA$ is a scaling matrix, so we have
$A = RSM$ where
\begin{align}
R &= Q^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} & \frac{-c}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} \\
   \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} & \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} \end{bmatrix}, \\
S &= T^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{ab + cd}{ad - bc} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \\
M &=
\begin{bmatrix} a \cos\theta - c \sin\theta & 0 \\
            0 & d \cos\theta + b \sin\theta \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{a^2 + c^2} & 0 \\
                    0 & \frac{ad - bc}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2}} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
That is, the $RSM$ decomposition is just like the $RMS$ decomposition except for the shear factor.

Comment: This is very helpful and instructive, thank you! I'll go through it carefully now. I'd originally convinced myself that $$S = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & s  \\
    s & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$  added no rotation by applying it to $n$ points evenly distributed around a unit circle, calculating $\theta_s$ of the transformed points for say $s=0.1$ and seeing that $\sum (\theta_s - \theta) = 0$. Indeed it stretches a non-rotated unit square (corner at origin) to a rhombus along it's diagonal and that "looked sheared to me" :-)

Comment: I agree that $\begin{bmatrix}1&s\\s&1\end{bmatrix}$ does not actually rotate things. It maps two perpendicular lines onto themselves, so I would classify it as a scaling transformation. It's just that the directions it scales in are not the $x$ and $y$ axes. A rotation (by any angle not a multiple of $2\pi$) does not map any line to itself, but preserves the distance of every point from the origin; a shear (other than the identity shear) maps exactly one line to itself (without scaling) and moves everything else parallel to that line.

Comment: There may be combinations of transformations other than one rotation, one scaling, and one shear that would do what you need. Perhaps two generalized scaling transformations (not necessarily only in the $x$ and $y$ directions) with a rotation in between. But that latter combination is seven parameters, whereas we have just four parameters for either the $RMS$ or $RSM$ decompositions above.